# powershell job session abort when one of the job fail

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Hi I am writing a job script in powershell which can execute it in parallel.

A sample code attached below to simulate the scenario. The script fail when we pass the  argument as "b" to the scriptblock.

```
$createZip = {
    Param ( [String] $source, [String] $zipfile )

    if ($source -eq "b") {
        throw "Failed to create $zipfile"
    }
    else {
        return "Successfully created $zipfile"
    }
}

$jobs = @()                          
$sources = "a", "b", "c"

foreach ($source in $sources) {
    Start-Job -Name $source -ScriptBlock $createZip -ArgumentList $source, "${source}.zip"
}


Get-Job | Wait-Job | Out-Null
```

If anyone of the job is getting failed, I need to abort all the running jobs.  How do i do that in powershell job.

Comment: Thanks TheIncorrigible for replying. Can you please give a sample code or a sample code link. I am little new to powershell scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cancel all jobs on the failure of one, you can do that like so:

```
$jobs = Get-Job

while ('Running' -in $jobs.State) {
    if ('Failed' -in $jobs.State) {
        $jobs | Stop-Job | Remove-Job
        break
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

---

Edit:
Here's an example of what your code *should* look like:

```
$createZip = {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $source,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string] $zipfile
    )

    if ($source -eq 'b') {
        throw "Failed to create $zipfile"
    } else {
        "Successfully created $zipfile"
    }
}

$sources = 'a', 'b', 'c'    
$jobs = foreach ($source in $sources) {
    Start-Job -Name $source -ScriptBlock $createZip -ArgumentList $source, "$source.zip"
}

'Queued'

while ('Running' -in $jobs.State) {
    $jobs.State

    if ('Failed' -in $jobs.State) {
        $jobs | Stop-Job | Remove-Job
        'Aborting jobs'
        break
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

Comment: What is that :check do?

Comment: @Vipin: It is a loop which will check the job state in a loop. If the it is failed, then he is stopping all the jobs.

Comment: @Vipin It's a loop label.  I've cleared up my example now.  It allows you to break nested loops how you want

Comment: Ok so ":check" is not required. And inside the if statement i just need check status and  break. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Vipin Basically.  I added the sleep in there so you're not burning all your CPU cycles running an infinite loop.  The `State` property updates on the object as the job is running so you don't need to repeatedly do `Get-Job`

Comment: Thanks TheIncorrigible1

Comment: @TheInCorrigitble1 The example code you shared is not working. Can you please help me.

Comment: Please find the sample code i tried https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Jn9p6n-hfjUzvwpqUDrOGBAi1rmUUJm/view

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 What is the difference between your script and my script? It looks same to me. But when I execute the script share by you, it works !!. Can you please share me, what was the change you did?

Comment: @Vipin For one, I don't delete any pre-existing jobs.  Also, I store all the jobs you create in the `$jobs` variable (`$jobs = foreach () { }`)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me on this. Have a nice day.